# How can I test how fast or slow my wordpress website it?

Tags: css, performance

I have my FIRST wordpress website and I love it, however I'm not sure if it's my browser (Firefox 8.0.1 for Mac) or my computer or the website itself but it's going really slow.

[MY SITE](http://safetyspeakers.ca) is in the finalizing stages and I want to make sure it's smooth. This is my first wordpress site so I can see myself adding a lot of things and maybe slowing it don that way?

First off, is it slow for you guys?

Where is a good site, plugin or article about how to determine how slow/fast your wordpress site it? Is there a handy plugin that can speed it up? Is there somewhere I can check to see how big my site it? What might be a specific thing slowing it down?

Comment: There are a lot of great suggestions here - Pingdom, Yslow (available as a Firebug for Firefox plugin), W3 Cache (WordPress caching plugin)...  I'd just like to add Firebug's "Net" tab will also give you a good breakdown of each element and its load time, letting you see exactly what's going fast or slow.  It loads for me in about 3-4 seconds, which isn't great but it's not as bad as some I've seen - caching should help a LOT with that.

Comment: I'll be using this today to work on the readiness and speed of my website. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great answers below, but my personal guess would be that your hosting service is not that great. What kind of hosting do you serve the blog from?

Comment: Well now the best hosting service but it's inexpensive for the kind of clients I have. I use GoDaddy. Once I have more high profile clients I'll look into my own hosting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Pingdom](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/).

Comment: I'd just like to second this one - pingdom is an excellent tool that will tell you exactly what's going on in a nice, easy to read format.

Comment: Yes indeed, in fact at my workplace we have pingdom speed test as a mandatory step in QA!

Comment: I'll be using this today to work on the readiness and speed of my website. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

You can meassure [Plugin performance with the P3 Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/p3-profiler/) pretty well. It will show you, which one of your plugins is the one that takes the most time and costs you the most resources.

[image]

Comment: I'll be using this today to work on the readiness and speed of my website. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

There are several factors that will make your Wordpress site slugish. One of the largest gains can be made with the W3 cache plugin, along with several other smaller fixes. Also choosing a well made theme can help with CSS & PHP bloat.

**Guide on Wordpress**
http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-ultimate-quickstart-guide-to-speeding-up-your-wordpress-site/

**General Google Speed assessment:**
https://developers.google.com/pagespeed/#url=http_3A_2F_2Fsafetyspeakers.ca_2F&mobile=false

**W3 Cache tutorial:**
http://www.techiezone.net/tutorials/configure-w3-total-cache/

**Edit
You also might want to checkout this book to *really* tweak it:
[http://www.amazon.com/High-Performance-Web-Sites-Essential/dp/0596529309](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596529309)

Comment: I'll be using this today to work on the readiness and speed of my website. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

I would strongly recommend using the [YSlow plugin](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) for your browser.

It provides useful feedback on what could be (is) slowing your site down.

Comment: I'll be using this today to work on the readiness and speed of my website. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [webpagetest.org](http://www.webpagetest.org/) where you'll get a graded report like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are several tools to check for Website speed: [7 Best Free Website Speed Tools](http://bacsoftwareconsulting.com/blog/index.php/web-design/best-free-website-speed-tools/)

You could also add code at the footer of your Website that measures the loading time of the page (does not work well with a caching plugin, understandably):

`<?php echo get_num_queries(); ?> <em title="Sometimes queries value does not update when page is cached.">queries</em> in <?php timer_stop(1); ?> seconds.`

Hope this helps.

Boutros.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there you can measure your website speed using several websites like Google Pagespeed insights , gtmetrix and webpagetest.org.

I find the later very easy and it explains in details what kind of problem your website faces.

You can also check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L6FhtmPAXk0) where you will learn how to test and understand your website speed.